# How do I obtain the public key from an ECDSA private key in Java with Bouncy Castle?

Tags: java, elliptic-curve, ecdsa

I've read [How do I obtain the public key from an ECDSA private key in OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480776/how-do-i-obtain-the-public-key-from-an-ecdsa-private-key-in-openssl)

and want to do the same thing, but in Java with Bouncy Castle.

I've also seen [Bouncy Castle ESCDA Create Public Key from Private Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003407/bouncy-castle-escda-create-public-key-from-private-key) but it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the following code, it's c# but in java it is similar. the private key is given by as base64 encoded string in this example and also a base64 encoded string is given back. the commented keyParameters are working, so use this one if you want to have key and curve.

```
private static readonly Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X9.X9ECParameters curve = Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Sec.SecNamedCurves.GetByName("secp256r1");
private static readonly Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.ECDomainParameters domain = new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.ECDomainParameters(curve.Curve, curve.G, curve.N, curve.H);
public string GetPublicKey(string privKey)
{
      Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger d = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(Convert.FromBase64String(privKey));
      //var privKeyParameters = new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.ECPrivateKeyParameters(d, domain);
      Org.BouncyCastle.Math.EC.ECPoint q = domain.G.Multiply(d);
      //var pubKeyParameters = new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters.ECPublicKeyParameters(q, domain);
      return Convert.ToBase64String(q.GetEncoded());
}
```